Determining Eulerian Cycle in Multigraph for Christofides Algorithm
I'm implementing the Christofides algorithm for solving the Traveling Salesman Problem and have reached the step where I need to find an Eulerian cycle in a multigraph. I'm unsure how to proceed when starting from a vertex with an odd degree after combining the MST and perfect weight matching edges. Here are the steps I've taken:
1. Minimum spanning tree

2. Perfect Weight Matching:

3. Multigraph (Combining MST and Perfect Weight Matching):

Given this multigraph, what should the Eulerian cycle be? Is the sequence 3->2->1->4->2 a valid Eulerian tour? Additionally, can an Eulerian path suffice in place of a cycle for the Christofides algorithm?

It's a multigraph, because there are two edges between node 2 and 3 in this example? (Edge(2,3) was contained in both.) The bottom plot only shows one, but if there are two, then you need to use both edges.

The graph should contain multiple edges between two nodes if an edge appears in both MST and PWM. The bottom plot only shows one edge between node 2 and 3, but in your case there should be two edges. Hence why it is a multigraph, not a simple graph.
When adding the edges correctly, all nodes will have even degree and you will not have this problem, you can find the Euler cycle easily.
If you work in Python, NetworkX has built in functionalities for multigraphs with MultiGraph(). If for some reason, you need to work with simple graphs and cannot allow parallel edges, you can actually turn the graph into a simple one: every time there is a double edge between two nodes, add 2 new nodes X and Y and replace the two edges with one edge that goes through X, and one that goes through Y (kind of like halving the edges with a middle node). This way, you still keep the Eulerian property, you still find Eulerian cycles, but you have a simple graph and can reconstruct the original multigraph from your graph simply.

Hello, do you know if the networkx function "networkx.eulerian_circuit" works on multigraphs?  The documentation specifies the input to be only a graph.  networx: eulerian_circuit
